# What's the reason why I'm having "foreign key mismatch" error on Room?

Tags: java, android-sqlite, android-room

I was trying to link my "Transaction" table to my "Envelope" table using a foreign key annotation Android room library provides. Basically, I want an envelope to have more than one transactions inside it.

#### Things I tried:

1. I've tried adding `@Column_info(names)` to the columns, but it is not doing anything.
2. I also tried checking if the values I passed to Transaction's constructor actually references a rowId on Envelope's table and it does.

These are my table POJOs:

#### Envelope class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "envelope")
@Fts3
public class Envelope {
    @ColumnInfo(name="rowid")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int rowid;
    private String name;
    private float balance;
    private float maxBalance;
    private String description;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date LastUpdatedAt;
```

#### Transaction class:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Envelope.class,
        parentColumns = "rowid",
        childColumns = "envelopeId",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Transaction {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float amount;
    @ColumnInfo(name="envelopeId")
    private int envelopeId;
    private String type; //can be "income" or "expense"
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date dateTransacted;
```

#### Here is the error:

```
SQLiteLog: (1) foreign key mismatch - "Transaction" referencing "envelope" in "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `Transaction` (`id`,`name`,`amount`,`envelopeId`,`type`,`dateTransacted`) VALUES (nullif(?, 0),?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Comment: There error message is useless unless knowing the values, which might not match.

Comment: I have checked the "envelopeId" value I want to add in the constructor of my Transaction's class to see if it matches an actual "rowId" value in my Envelope's class and it  is really there.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I run into the same problem after I added @Fts4 to one of my entities and changed the column name to "rowid". The values seem to fit, but I get the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you annotate your "working entity" as an FTS-indexed entity which makes the primary key no longer usable as a foreign key (the documentation is a little unclear here).

You could drop the `@Fts3` on your Envelope class and create an extra FTS-entity which maps to your original entity using `@Fts4` (which lets you specify the content entity).

```
@Fts4(contentEntity = Envelope.class)
@Entity(tableName = "envelopes_fts")
public class EnvelopeFts {
// The fields you want to index with getters and setters
}
```

At least I could only get my foreign keys to work again after I split my source entity and the corresponding FTS-entity in two separate Room-entities.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me an idea on what I should do next.

Comment: Is there a source about this? This seems to be a valid reason for me, and saved me from another 3 hours of debugging...

Comment: Hmm, I can't really remember, but I think it was rather a trial and error approach, since I did not link anything here... Glad that it helped you, too!

Comment: I've check the syntax: [CREATE TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) has constraint (and therefore can be used as foreign key), but [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html) doesn't. It is explicitly mentioned that FTS [3, 4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) and [5](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html) all create virtual tables, so that's the reason. The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) about virtual table doesn't explicit specify that no constraint can be created though.